# htaccess redirection

Tags: .htaccess

i want to redirect `test.com/8/`   to `test.com/8`
the number section is not fixed, so i need something includes **[0-9]*...**

Comment: That's great. What have you tried? Are you having trouble with your configuration? Do you get an error? Does it not work as expected? Does any other redirect configuration work?

Comment: if you want always to drop this look at :
http://forums.site-reference.com/topic/10179/How-can-Remove-Backslash-From-URL-Using-htaccess/

Comment: i tried to correct from the code but it's not practice, so i want to do this with .htaccess but i don't know how can i do...
i use this folder design for mod_rewrite it works well but when i put slash end of the link it goes bad.

Comment: haim it redirects url to test.com/8/ to test.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test.com/([0-9]+)/$ test.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Remember, flag R is important to force a external redirection